# IDE C9 install locally from GitHub

Tags: cloud9-ide

do you have any "how-to" for that?

Answer (score 15):

Installing cloud9 sdk is much simpler now. Make sure you have nodejs and git installed.

Then run

```
git clone https://github.com/c9/core sdk
cd sdk
./scripts/install-sdk.sh
```

To launch cloud9 use

```
node server.js -p 8181 -l 0.0.0.0 -a :
```

This works on windows too, when running from cygwin or msys (which comes with default git installation). If you do not have python2.7 and visual studio installed npm will not be able to build pty.js and terminals won't work, but everything else will work normally.
On windows there is also `bin/launch.bat` script to launch cloud9 from explorer gui

Comment: is that like a full install , or just env for plugin develop ?

Comment: both, you can pass `-w /path/to/folder` to edit another folder. Also see http://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/v0.1/docs/the-licenses-for-cloud9-sdk-and-packages#the-core-sdk